# Delete Project in Bot

Tags: ios, xcode, git, xcode-bots

I knew how to delete Bot project in XCode , but I have a problem ,
If the XCode project does not exist anymore , how should I do to delete project in Bot ?

I have two test projects in XCode Bot,
but they are not exist in our git server and XCode project files were deleted ....

how should I do to delete project in Bot ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

ha ha ....in Bot webpage upper right

[image]